# How to allocate and maintain memory in library code?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

In my current project my program needs to call a library to build communication with server. For some needs, I need to modify the library code so that it can allocate memory and the allocated memory exists unless I invoke some function in the library to free it. I don't have too much exposure to libraries and to me a library is just like an API that can be invoked by multiple programs. Therefore a library does not have its lifespan. From my understanding, if my program invokes a function in the library, the function allocates the memory and does some work, but after everything is done, the library code just "rests" and the pointer to that memory will vanish. So is there any way to solve that? If my understanding is wrong, can you give me some guide? Thank you!

Comment: You have your answer (even if this text-only question is pretty vague): _"...allocated memory exists unless I invoke some function in the library to free it..."_.

Comment: dynamic memory, once allocated, will remain valid for use until you `free()` it or finish the execution of the application [whichever earlier]. If you do not `free()` them, it's called a `memory leak`.

Comment: @Adriano Like Sourav Ghosh said, there will be a memory leak. Is it really safe not to free the memory? Besides even the memory is there, how can I access to it if the pointer will vanish?

Comment: Pointer will not _vanish_. If needed you can keep a list of allocated objects (to free when quitting) but usually it's even simpler: suppose you have `create_object()` that allocates memory and returns a pointer to that memory. Library users will use it then they'll need to call a `free_object()` method. They don't know what's what, how it's allocated and where because it's completely managed by your library. Opposite case is, for example, when you use `strdup`. Memory is allocated by _library_ but its users have responsability to call `free` to release it when they're done with that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the typical solution if the library needs to maintain internal state is to add an entrypoint to the library that must be called before any other API function.

Such a function is often called the "initializer function", i.e. `mylibrary_init()` or something. Then you can have `mylibrary_deinit()` or something to close the library down, freeing the state.

If the library needs to handle multiple users in the same program, the state needs to be somehow made public, so that the `init()` function returns some kind of state identifier that needs to be passed with all other API calls, to keep them apart.

Comment: Hi unwind, thank you for answering my question. Initializer function seems like a good way to solve my problem even though I have no clue about how it works and how to implement it... And actually I don't want the library to allocate memory at the very beginning. It will only allocate memory when the program invokes certain functions in the library code and if the memory has been already allocated, then there is no need to allocate any more.